# Tensorflow Multi-layer perceptron graph won't converge

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to python and tensorflow. After better(maybe) understanding DNN and its math. I start to learn to use tensorflow by exercises.

One of my exercises is to predict x^2. Which means after fine training. When I give 5.0, it will predict 25.0.

## Parameters and settings:

Cost function = E((y-y')^2)

Two hidden Layers and they are fully connected.

learning_rate = 0.001

n_hidden_1 = 3

n_hidden_2 = 2

n_input = 1

n_output = 1

```
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

def generate_input():
    import random

    val = random.uniform(-10000, 10000)
    return np.array([val]).reshape(1, -1), np.array([val*val]).reshape(1, -1)


# tf Graph input
# given one value and output one value
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1])
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
distance = tf.sub(pred, y)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(distance, 2))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    avg_cost = 0.0

    for iter in range(10000):
        inp, ans = generate_input()
        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: inp, y: ans})
        print('iter: '+str(iter)+' cost='+str(c))
```

However, it turns out that c sometimes gets larger,and sometimes lower. (but it is big)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your training data have big range because of the statement `val = random.uniform(-10000, 10000)`, try to do some data preprocessing before you train. for example,

```
val = random.uniform(-10000, 10000)
val = np.asarray(val).reshape(1, -1)
val -= np.mean(val, axis=0)
val /= np.std(val, axis=0)
```

As for loss value, it's ok that sometimes it gets larger,and sometimes lower, just make sure the loss is decreasing when training epoch increase in general. PS: we are often using SGD optimizer.

Comment: thanks, I now use average cost and I see it descend. The reason why we should scale the input is for cost function to work better? Am I right? If input value range is too big. the cost become bigger even if it is acceptable. for example 100^2 = 10000 and it predicts 9800. the cost would be 200^2. However changing cost function would need to change optimizer. Here is my understanding so far. please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: yes, big value will take more time to converge. And about optimizer, different cost functions can use the same optimizer, but in general we choose SGD for simplicity.